# Se puede llamar a un constructor(no por defecto) desde new

Tags: c++, constructor

Estoy haciendo una tabla hash, en la que cada celda tiene varias claves, lo que hice es un objeto llamado celda en el que se guarda a forma de array las distintas claves de la tabla. Dentro del objeto de la tabla, a su vez, tengo un vector de celdas. El tema es que tengo este código:

En el objeto de la tabla hash

```
#define Tablon
#include <vector>

template <class T >

class Tabla{

private:
std::vector<T> vCelda;
int size;

public:

Tabla(int n_celdas,int s_celda/*,int f_disp,int f_exp*/):

    vCelda(n_celdas,celda(s_celda))
    {
    }
```

En el objeto celda

```
template <class T>
class celda{

    private:
        int  nClaves;
        T* claves;
        int libres;
    public:

        celda(int nC ){

            nClaves=nC;
            claves = new T [nClaves];
            libres=nClaves; 
        }

vCelda=new celda<T> [n_celdas] (s_celda) ;
```

Cuando lo compilo para ver si esta bien me da el siguiente error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
tabla.hpp: In constructor ‘Tabla<T>::Tabla(int, int)’:
tabla.hpp:20:26: error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
     vCelda(n_celdas,celda(s_celda))
```

Si pongo la siguiente linea:

```
vCelda(n_celdas,celda<T>(s_celda))
```

Salta el siguiente error:

```
 In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
 tabla.hpp: In instantiation of ‘Tabla<T>::Tabla(int, int) [with T = DNI]’:
 main.cpp:39:37:   required from here
 tabla.hpp:20:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<DNI, std::allocator<DNI> >::vector(int&, celda<DNI>)’
      vCelda(n_celdas,celda<T>(s_celda))
                                  ^
```

He probado quitar el parámetro en paréntesis, pero obviamente da otro fallo, pues no hay constructor por defecto vacío. Me pregunto si C++ contiene alguna forma predefinida para realizar este tipo de operaciones.

Comment: que seria n_celdas en tu primer constructor? no entiendo bien que logica buscas con estos constructores

Comment: Nceldas viene a ser el número de celdas dentro de la tabla has es decir las filas, mientras que s_celda corresponde con el número de claves que caben en una misma celda, es decir columnas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal y como dice el error, **no** se puede usar constructores con argumentos en el `operator new[]`.

Se puede usar la inicialización entre llaves:

```
vCelda = new celda<T> [n_celdas] { s_celda };
```

Pero esta opción es bastante limitada ... solo inicializará el número exacto de elementos que indiques ... **o uses el valor literal `0`**. Pero claro, en ese caso, podrías usar directamente el constructor por defecto.

Puesto que, de todas formas, estás usando memoria dinámica, tu mejor opción es usar un `std::vector< >`:

```
#include <vector>

template <class T > class Tabla {
  std::vector< celda< T > > vCelda;

public:
  Tabla( int n_celdas, int s_celda /*, int f_disp, int f_exp*/ ) :
    vCelda( n_celdas, celda( s_celda ) ) {
  }
};
```

Lo inicializas directamente con el tamaño deseado, y como segundo argumento le pasas una referencia `const`al valor que quieres introducir, con lo cual dicho valor **es copiado a todos los elementos del `std::vector< >`**.

Comment: Hola buenas, muchas gracias, hize el cambio pero: 1. dentro de la linea:  vCelda( n_celdas, celda( s_celda ) )  falta la template, (lo digo por si hay otra persona con el mismo problema leyendo), 2. Intente ponerle la template pero no me deja tampoco, dice que vector no lo permite. Muchas gracias

Comment: @k1k4ss0 Edita la pregunta y añade los cambios que has hecho, porque usar el `std::vector< >` es perfectamente válido. En algo no me he explicado bien. ¡ Ah, y quita el `check` ! No lo pongas hasta que no esté resuelto.

Comment: ya esta corregido

Comment: @k1k4ss0 Vale, ya lo he visto ... en `class celda { T *claves;` ... pero `celda` no es una plantilla, a no ser que la declares **dentro** de `Tabla`. Un [mcve] viene muy bien en estos casos :-)

Comment: vale ya vi el fallo, cuando declaro el vector, lo hago std::vector<T>, y es std::vector<celda<T>>... Muchas gracias

Comment: @k1k4ss0 ¡ Ah carajo ! Edito y lo arreglo. ¡ El fallo era mio al final ! :-O

Comment: XDXDXDXDXD, igual mente muchas gracias!